# php GUI mode is not appear on my browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

i'm using cenots 6.4 32 bit os
i have download phpMyAdmin-4.1.2-all-languages.tar
nd i have extract to /var/www/html
i have also change authentication cookie to 'http' in php.inc.php.
when i open browser and type

localhost/phpmyadmin

][1]**!
then
only php files appears on my browser but php GUI mode is not appear on my browse. and it does not ask me username and password.
however i have restart service successfully httpd, mysqld

Comment: "then only php files appears on my browser" it looks like PHP code is just being rendered instead of being executed, did you install PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install PHP as well.

Comment: Sverri M. Olsen: on the contrary, this looks like the good answer to this question.

Comment: How is this not an answer? He's seeing raw PHP code because PHP is not installed.